# Change a property on NSManagedObject, does it send a notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Can I change a property on a NSManagedObject in one location and get a notification somewhere else?

I need to download a bunch of photos and each photo's information from a server. In my Data Model, I retrieve all the photo's information, then pass the `NSManagedObject` to a custom `UIView` to display the photo and photo's image. I do not set a `UIImageView`'s image yet cause I don't have it.

My model then begins retrieving each photo from the server asynchronously. When a photo has completed downloading, I want to set the `NSManagedObject` property for the photo (just a NSData property). When I do that, I want the custom `UIView` to get a notification that the object changed and set `UIImaveView`'s image to what was just downloaded.

Is it possible for my custom `UIView` to tell when the NSManagedObject has changed?

I only ask cause I have noticed when I add a Catagory to a `NSManagedObject`, when I want to set a property, it is recommended to do it like:

```
-(void)setHasNewData:(NSNumber *)hasNewData {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"hasNewData"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:hasNewData forKey:@"hasNewData"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"hasNewData"];

    self.modifiedDateLocal = [NSDate date];
}
```

Comment: What wrong with `NSNotificationCenter postNotification`?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would not recommend doing a set accessor like that.  You are better off using a dynamic property and then overriding the lifecycle method `-willSave` and setting the modified date there.  That way you are getting the modified date of when it is saved to disk and the update to the modification date happens *once* per save.  You can do something like:

```
- (void)willSave
{
  [super willSave];
  if ([self changedValues][@"modifiedDateLocal"] == nil) return;
  [self setModifiedDateLocal:[NSDate date]];
}
```

When a save happens, Core Data will call `-willSave` on every entity just before the save occurs.  If an entity changes something then the process is started over again.  Therefore we check to make sure that we didn't already modify the `modifiedDateLocal` to avoid an infinite loop.

As for your UIView, you can either use KVO (Key Value Observing) to watch for a property on a specific instance of a `NSManagedObject` or you can listen for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` which will fire any time any property on any entity changes.  Be warned though, it is very chatty and therefore expensive.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is let the custom view make the server call to download and display when complete and save the changes. This seems to break the MVC but seems most straight forward.

Comment: That would be bad.  You do not want to wire up your view controller to network calls.  View controllers should listen to Core Data.